# If $a,b$ are the roots of the equation $x^2-2x+3=0$ obtain the equation whose roots are $a^3-3a^2+5a-2$, $b^3-b^2+b+5$

Tags: quadratics

I have been trying this using sum of roots and product of roots but it gets too lengthy. So I found the roots of the given equation which are imaginary and tried to replace the values in the two given roots. Still I am not able to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$ a^3-3a^2+5a-2=(a-1)(a^2-2a+3)+1=1$$
and
$$b^3-b^2+b+5=(b+1)(b^2-2b+3)+2=2. $$
So the desired polynomial is 
$$ (X-1)(X-2)=X^2-3X+2.$$

Comment: Brilliant. Now, why would any teacher ask this question, is beyond my imagination.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not very well formulated: if you want a degree-two polynomial with roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, just take
$$
(x-\alpha)(x-\beta). 
$$
The way the problem is phrased it is clear that something else is expected, but I cannot imagine what.

Comment: See Hagen von Eitzen's answer above.